# Callback parameter not working JSONP javascript

Tags: jsonp

I'm trying to load the data form cross-domain using JSONP. callback parameters that passed in a script isn't printing any data in the console.

I'll load `week-7.js` from another server but I try it locally it is not working. I can not change any code in serverside part I don't have access to change it

I put this `<script>` in HTML

```
<button onclick="clickButton()">click me</button>

<script>
    function renderTable(data){
      console.log(data)
    }

    function clickButton() {
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.type = "text/javascript"
      s.src = "week-7.js?callback=renderTable";
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
</script>
```

this is my week-7.js

```
const data = {
  "noWeek": 1,
  "fstWeek": 1,
  "week": 1,
  "end": 1591459131848,
  "profiles": {
    "test1": {
      "id": "test1",
      "type": "3",
      "name": "test test",
      "picture": {
        "uri": "/flag.png"
      },
      "country": "IN",
      "ed": 1,
      "gs": 100,
      "ts": 13.0,
      "in": 31,
      "px": 34
    }
  },
  "leaders": [
    "test1"
  ]
}
```

Is there anything wrong? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started you could:

1 - Alter your local data file to jsnop by removing '=' and starting it with 'data({' and put a closing bracket ')' at the end.

2 - Add this to your HTML:

```
<h3>Output</h3>
<div id='x'></div>
```

3 - Change your callback function to:

```
function data(y){
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(y, null, 2)
}
```

If you manually add your callback function name (data) to the data file you will not need to to put a callback name in the calling script - it will be ignored locally and perhaps by the server. However if you are getting third party remote data from eg Yahoo finance you will probably need to put a callback name in the URL and perhaps use a service such as https://json2jsonp.com

The process works by changing you data file into a function call to your callback function.

A word of warning. Things may stop working if you add further related script outside of the callback function. Get it working inside the function first.

Good luck.